# Hadoop ignores filesystem location config on Windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, windows-10, hadoop2

I am trying to install single node hadoop on Windows 10.

I have used various guides, but failed. Last one I used was https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10

I have confogured my dfs as

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.replication</name> 
    <value>1</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
    <value>file:///V:/DB/hadoop/namenode</value> 
</property>

<property> 
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
    <value>file:///V:/DB/hadoop/datanode</value> 
</property>
```

Formatting went well.

Unfortunately, when I run `start-all`, I get in one of windows

```
18/04/22 21:36:17 WARN datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir V:\DB\hadoop\datanode :
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Directory is not readable: V:\DB\hadoop\datanode
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2580)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2753)
18/04/22 21:36:17 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/V:/DB/hadoop/datanode/"
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2544)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2753)
```

Looks like it has problems with local Windows path specification. What to do?

Comment: Did you create those directories and give permission by `winutils` to them?

Comment: I didn't, but formatting creates them.

Comment: Can you run a `winutils chmod 777 V:\DB\hadoop\datanode`?

Comment: Hi @Dims, did you get the solution here? I am facing the same issue.